# Why AngularJS is changing values of the objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services, angular-http

My AngularJS service code -

```
this.getEducation = function (id) {
            var url = 'SOME_URL/?party_id=' + id;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(url).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("could not get education info");
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Now, my service is returning a data like this -

```
[
  {
    "id": 22,
    "party_id": 9,
    ...
    "university": "UoP",
    "created_at": "2015-07-13 17:09:52",
    "degree": "BE"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "party_id": 9,
   ...
    "university": "UoP",
    "created_at": "2015-07-13 17:11:06",
    "degree": "ME"
  }
]
```

Now, here's the problem - when the `data` being resolved in promise, contains following array -

```
[
      {
        "id": 22,
        "party_id": 9,
        ...
        "university": "UoP",
        "created_at": "2015-07-13 17:09:52",
        "degree": "BE"
      },
      {
        "id": 23,
        "party_id": 9,
       ...
        "university": null,
        "created_at": "2015-07-13 17:11:06",
        "degree": null
      }
    ]
```

So, my question is, WHY AngularJS setting some values of my array elements to null ???

P.S. I'm using the data retrieved by this in controller, assigning it to scope variable, and doing ng-repeat on forms.

Edit :
My controller code is as follows

```
 $scope.educationInformations = [];
 $scope.setEducation = function () {
            EducationProvider.getEducation(id).then(
                function (educations) {

                    angular.forEach(educations, function(education){
                        console.log(education);
                  $scope.educationInformations.push({education:education});
                        console.log($scope.educationInformations);
                    })
            });
        };
```

THIS works, (console log is accurate)

Now, This is my template code.
When this is used,

```
<div ng-repeat="educationInfo in educationInformations">
<input-text ng-model="educationInfo.education.university"></input-text>
</div>
```

Now `input-text` is a directive created by me..
Directive code -

```
.directive('inputText', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'views/inputText.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            }
        };
    });
```

Directive template

```
<input class="form-control" 
ng-model="ngModel" ng-init="ngModel = null">
```

Comment: I have a hard time believing angular is the cause of this. More debugging is needed.

Comment: Did you look at the data coming back from your `$http.get` request by inspecting the actual response?  Does it have `null`s?

Comment: is that expect data verified, or just what you assume is coming in?

Comment: To debug further, start by going to your browser network tab and inspecting the request. Are the values null there? Yes? server problem. No? continue. Next add some logging to your service. Is it null there? Yes? provide that code. No? continue. Next add some logging to your controller. Is it null there? Yes? provide that code. No? I don't believe in magic, so you shouldn't get this far.

Comment: Hello, this is really driving me crazy, why it is happening. I'm stuck like 5 hours.
@KevinB : is this has something to do with I'm assigning the same array to score variables (models) and repeating them in a form?

Comment: @KevinB : I already did that, the data posted above is the actual response from the request

Comment: Not sure, i'd have to see code.

Comment: So, your console.log in the success callback has the nulls?

Comment: Then your looping shouldn't have anything to do with it. remove the looping.

Comment: If the console.log has nulls then the problem is on the server side and has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: @KevinB : After removing the looping from controller (and template) the console log on success is correct.
But why a data retrieved from service has anything to do with whatever controller does with it?

Comment: I mean there is no binding, at all, between controller and service, right?

Comment: console.log can be tricky at times. If you used a debugger statement instead, you would have seen values instead of nulls, at which point you would have followed the problem on to find the src, :)

Comment: you passed `data` to the resolve, so anything you do to it will affect `data` as well, because it's the same object. By the time you expanded the object in your console, the controller had already modified it, so the console showed the modified object.

Comment: Oh!!!! If this is the case, then it is a design flaw maybe! As services and controllers does not have data binding, Angular should create separate objects when the data is retrieved in controller, from service.

Comment: no...you as developer need to understand object inheritance and what object references are. Also should have posted code so people can help better and aren't completely guessing at what is happening

Comment: Hi @KevinB : I've updated the code in question, also I've solved the problem - and answered to the question myself!
Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the directive template code as follows

```
<input class="form-control" 
ng-model="ngModel" ng-init="ngModel">
```

Your code was setting ng-model to null ( `ng-init = "ngModel = null` ), as you have two way binding with controller, this initialization to null would affect the controller scope objects.